# is there a way to tell JDBC I am about to execute a transaction?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

When setting AutoCommit to false; does this mean that I have to commit after executing every SQL command in my application.

Here's a scenario

SQL1 doesn't need to be a transaction.
SQL2 needs to be a transaction.

If I set AutoCommit to false, does that mean I have to alter all my code, and put "commit" after every SQL1 like commands ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `AutoCommit` to `true` when you want to execute SQL statements individually.  Every SQL statement will automatically be executed in its own individual transaction.

Set `AutoCommit` to `false` when you want to bundle multiple SQL statements into a single transaction and commit the transaction after all SQL statements have executed.

The way I read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html), a transaction is implicitly created when you execute your first SQL statement.  It then commits immediately if `AutoCommit` is set to `true`, or continues accepting further SQL statements into the transaction until you manually commit, if `AutoCommit` is set to `false`.

Comment: Just to note, you have to use `Connection#setAutocommit` before executing any statement or make sure that all the connections have `autocommit = false` on creation, which depends on the parameters sent to the driver manager when creating the connection.